# Difference between 'I don't know how can I' and 'I don't know how I can'?

Tags: word-order, interrogatives, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I am confused between

> I don't know how can I do this

and

> I don't know how I can do this

Can anyone explain difference between these sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't know **how I can do this**" is correct.

The emboldened expression is a subordinate interrogative clause: it is a clause that's embedded in the main clause and serves as a complement of the verb "know".

The subordinate interrogative differs from the main interrogative in that it does not allow the subject-auxiliary inversion to occur (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002: p. 972):

> The main structural difference between subordinate and main clause interrogatives is the subject-auxiliary inversion does not generally apply in the subordinate construction:
>
> MAIN:
>
> i. Has he read it? 
>   ii. What did he do?
>
> SUBORDINATE
>
> i. I wonder [whether/if he has read it].
>   ii. I know [what he did].

It's possible, however, to the use the 'inverted' version when the clause is not fully attached to the main clause, in which case, it may be separated by a punctuation mark such as the colon or the em-dash.

> The subject-auxiliary inversion is not wholly excluded from the subordinate interrogatives, but it's largely restricted (in Standard English) to constructions where questions are cited, as in *Easily the most popular question put to the PM was: Why are we buying the New Zealand carpets for the new Parliament House?* (p. 973)